# How to connect multiple Pi Zero ethernet gadgets to a Pi 2?

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, cluster

I followed [this](http://blog.gbaman.info/?p=699) guide to turn my Raspberry Pi Zeroes into ethernet gadgets and I did not change anything in the `/etc/network/interfaces` or `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` files. All of the SD cards were fresh installs of Raspbian Jessie Lite from March 2016.
I connected 3 of them to my Raspberry Pi 2 to experiment with a little cluster.

The issue is that when I have more than one Pi Zero connected to the Pi 2, I can communicate with only one of them at a time.
If I ping each of them, only one will be reachable and that's the only one I can ssh into. If I reboot it through ssh the problem continues, but with another Pi Zero responding to a ping and accepting ssh connections.

I am not familiar with network configuration. How can I make all my Pi Zeroes visible to my Pi 2 at the same time?

EDIT: Each Raspberry Pi have a different hostname, I'm using `hostname.local` to ping and ssh.

EDIT 2: When I ran `ip neighbor` I saw that it is trying to reach all of the Pi Zeroes on the same interface, is there a way to select the correct interface for communication?

```
169.254.249.84 dev usb0  FAILED
169.254.189.237 dev usb0 lladdr 76:5d:7b:bc:be:2d STALE
169.254.101.161 dev usb0  FAILED
```

Comment: This guide should solve your problem: http://raspberryjamberlin.de/zero360-part-2-connecting-via-otg-a-cluster-of-raspberry-pi-zeros-to-a-pi-3/#PiUDEV